# How to add component group to analytics sidekick?

Tags: analytics, aem

In Adobe Experience Manager (AEM) (CQ 5.6.1) you can configure the variable mappings for a SiteCatalyst report suite. This configuration page is found at:

```
http://localhost:4502/cf#/etc/cloudservices/sitecatalyst/my-config/my-framework.html
```

To add a component to the configuration you drag the component from the sidekick to the page. The component will only appear in the sidekick if it has a configured "analytics" child node.

Typically a component will appear in the sidekick under the group name specified in its configured `componentGroup` attribute.  However, the analytics sidekick seems to only support the following groups and any other `componentGroup` is lumped into "Other".

- General
- Commerce
- Search&Promote
- Social Plugins
- Other

In other words, if I change my component's `componentGroup` to "Commerce", then my component will appear under "Commerce" but if I change my component's `componentGroup` to "Custom", it will appear under "Other".

How can a new custom group be added to the sidekick groups?  The list of groups must be specified somewhere in the CRX, but I can't seem to track it down.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The sidekick will only show up to a certain number of named component groups (default to 4).  Anything more than that gets lumped into a 5th "Other" group, ignoring the group defined in the componentGroup property.  Check out this info: http://forums.adobe.com/message/5029192

> If there is a need to change, you can overlay the script found in
>
> "/libs/cq/ui/widgets/source/widgets/wcm/ComponentList.js" and modify
> the constant value
>
> CQ.wcm.ComponentList.MAX_GROUPS = 4;
>
> CQ.wcm.ComponentList.MIN_COMPS = 3;

So most likely since there are already 4 analytics groups defined by the system, you can't add your own because all the available slots are already filled.  You'd likely need to modify the defaults first to allow more groups--or potentially remove *everything* from one of the existing groups so that group no longer shows.

Answer (score 0):

Just for clarification...did you configure the "Group" in the analytics node for the components you're trying to expose to the SiteCatalyst framework? Assuming you're defining the analytics node outside of CRXDE (in your IDE), here's an example of analytics.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<jcr:root xmlns:sling="http://sling.apache.org/jcr/sling/1.0" xmlns:cq="http://www.day.com/jcr/cq/1.0" xmlns:jcr="http://www.jcp.org/jcr/1.0"
    jcr:primaryType="nt:unstructured"
    cq:componentGroup="My Group"
    cq:componentName="Button"
    cq:trackevents="myEvent"
    cq:trackvars="someVar,anotherVar"/>
```

You need to make sure you set cq:componentGroup here. The componentGroup property set on the component configuration itself won't do it for you.

It wasn't clear to me in your initial question if this is what you meant, when you said you configured the componentGroup.

One other thing to think about is that I've seen some funny behavior with this framework. When you try to expose analytics properties from components that have some complex inheritance to them, I've seen CQ fail to add them to the Sidekick. I haven't diagnosed the issue yet (or isolated steps to reproduce), but I think there are some fringe-case bugs there. You may want to consider if that's a possibility, as well.